# auto-increment by information_schema

Tags: mysql

I  have a table `member`. I want to make an user id using auto increment.
I have tried using the following:

```
SET new.user_id = CONCAT(new.name, LPAD((SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM 
information_schema.TABLES WHERE
TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = 'member'),3,'0'));
```

But when I inserted a new member, i've got an error message `user_id cannot be null` and the data wasn't added. I want the user id will shown like `jos001` as an primary key.

Please help me.. how to make it happen?

Comment: not very clear, you have an autoincrement primary key, right?

Comment: sorry, bad english. I've no AI primary key

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do. Create a table with an autoincrement primary key and you're done.

Comment: no, the `member` table, which you don't describe.

Comment: check this out (stackoverflow.com/questions/469009/can-you-access-the-auto-increment-value-in-mysql-within-one-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this BEFORE INSERT trigger -

**Full script:**

```
CREATE TABLE member(
  user_id VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL
);

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON member
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  -- Find next id for new user - MAX+1
  SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(user_id, LENGTH(user_id) - 2, 3) AS SIGNED)) + 1 INTO @next_id
    FROM member WHERE SUBSTRING(user_id, 1, LENGTH(user_id) - 3) = NEW.name;

  SET NEW.user_id = CONCAT(NEW.name, LPAD(IFNULL(@next_id, 1), 3,'0'));
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Insert some records:**

```
INSERT INTO member VALUES('', 'jos');
INSERT INTO member VALUES('', 'jos');
INSERT INTO member VALUES('', 'jos');
INSERT INTO member VALUES('', 'alex');
INSERT INTO member VALUES('', 'alex');
INSERT INTO member VALUES('', 'jos');
```

**Check result:**

```
SELECT * FROM member;

+---------+------+
| user_id | name |
+---------+------+
| jos001  | jos  |
| jos002  | jos  |
| jos003  | jos  |
| alex001 | alex |
| alex002 | alex |
| jos004  | jos  |
+---------+------+
```

Comment: Have a look at full example. I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an UPDATE/TRIGGER shown in the query you provided.

An update will work after the INSERT. The TRIGGER will not work if it is on the same database (as it might end up in an infinite loop)

What you should do, is do this with any programming language you use before you try to insert. Have the to be inserted name ready when you do the insert.